# How to divide html page

Tags: html, css

I want to make a html page with three sections and inside each section divide it to left and right. In each section I have three boxes and I want to put two boxes on the left and one box on the right following is the css and html code:

```css
.leftbox {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  
 }

 .rightbox {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  
 }
```

```html
<div id="rotationFormPopup" class="rotationFormPopup" style="width: 900px; display: none; background: #FFF; border: 1px solid; padding: 10px; margin-top: 100px;">
 <h2 class="popup-header">Rotation Forms</h2>

 <div class="newRotation-sections">


  <h3>Details</h3>
  <div class="newRotation-section-1" style="margin-top: 10px;">

   <div class="leftbox">
    <span>Mob</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="newRotation-mob" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br />

    <span>Paddock</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="newRotation-paddock" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br />
   </div>
   <div class="rightbox">

    <span>Date</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="newRotation-date" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; float: left; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><br /><br />
   </div>

  </div>
  
  <h3>Fencing options</h3>
  
  <div class="newRotation-section-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <div class="leftbox">

    <span>Available Today</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="newRotation-available" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br />

    <span>Paddock Allocation %</span> <br />
    <input type="number" class="newRotation-alloc" value="50" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br />

   </div>
   <div class="rightbox">
    <span>Required Result</span> <br />
    <input type="text" class="newRotation-result" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br />
   </div>

  </div>
  <h3>Assign As Task</h3>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I receive the below result, I don't know why the fencing options jump to the right side.

Here is the image of my work:
[image]

Comment: _“I don't know why the fencing options jump to the right side.”_ - because there’s space for it there, and you did not _clear_ the previous floats.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up this using the Bootstrap Framework. It matches your image exactly.

There's a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/YRJoWV)** if you want to fork and play around with it. It's responsive, too.

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h5 class="title text-uppercase bg-success text-white p-1">Rotation Forms</h5>
      <h4 class="mb-3 mt-3">Details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mob">Mob</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" placeholder="Enter Mob">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paddock">Paddock</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paddock" placeholder="Enter Paddock">          
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Enter Date">          
      </div>      
      <h4 class="mb-3 mt-3">Fencing Options</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="avail">Available Today</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="avail" placeholder="NaN">          
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="allocation">Paddock Allocation %</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="allocation" placeholder="100">          
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="result">Required Result</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result" placeholder="NaN">          
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <h4 class="mb-3 mt-3">Assign As Task</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="assign">Assign to</label><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="assign">Add</button>       
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checked">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="checked">I want to see this too.</label>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Cancel</button>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```